# How to use integers from user input in a Math equation

Tags: java, user-input

The user inputs a number of yards, and then I want to use that number and multiple it by 3 to give the answer in feet.

### So far the code looks like this:

```
 Scanner userYards = new Scanner(System.in);  
 System.out.println("How many yards?");
 int userName = userYards.nextInt();  // Read user input
 feet = yards * 3;
```

---

I obviously know that the yards variable is not in use yet. I am confused on where to go from the user input and how to call it.

Comment: You take the User Input and store it in `userName` variable so you need to change feet to be `feet = userName *3;`

Comment: Important side-note: `userYards` is a reference to `Scanner` object and not whatever you enter, so don't name it as `userYards`. Scanner is a InputStream reader, so name it like `scanner` and then use read whatever you want from that object, like `scanner.read...();`.

Answer (score 0):

just change the variable "feet", and declare it.

```
 Scanner userYards = new Scanner(System.in);  
 System.out.println("How many yards?");
 int userName = userYards.nextInt();  // Read user input
 int feet = userName * 3;
```

So, I've changed yards to userName and declared the "feet" variable. This way, you must get what you want to achieve. I believe that userName is not the best option to name this variable, I guess you could put just yards, like that:

```
Scanner userYards = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("How many yards?");
int yards = userYards.nextInt();  // Read user input
int feet = yards * 3;
```